# C# asp dropdownlist databind empty dataset selectedindex

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Situation:
I'm populating a DropDownList's SqlDatasource with a variable SQL string that depends on user input on a page (using different tables as needed). After setting the appropriate string, I use a DataBind of the SqlDataSource to fill the dropdown with the appropriate data, and manually add one option ("All") to the values. I'm doing this in the Page_Load of the page (that's when I know what SQL string to use).

Problem:
This works fine, as long as the SQL doesn't return an empty dataset. If it does, the page initially loads with empty dropdownlist values except "All". After that, whatever I do (for example, click some completely unrelated button) I get in the NEXT Page_Load of the page:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
  Message='KLFDDropDownList' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
SelectedIndex value is 0.

What am I doing wrong?

```
if (Typeselection == "3") KLFDSqlDataSource.SelectCommand = KLFDSQLhistorie; 
else KLFDSqlDataSource.SelectCommand = KLFDSQL; 
KLFDSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Clear();
KLFDSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("GBID", DbType.String, userName);
//User.Identity.Name); 
//TODO KLFDDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you are passing dropdown selected index as a index for its data source, as from drop down you are getting index 0 but data source is empty so there is no 0 index

Comment: at the page load , are you using dropdown selected index value

Comment: no, not using it. Not even used the dd on the initial load that succeeded (with an empty set too...)

Comment: can you please post some code, or that line on which you are getting error?

Comment: <code>            if (Typeselection == "3")
                KLFDSqlDataSource.SelectCommand = KLFDSQLhistorie;
            else
                KLFDSqlDataSource.SelectCommand = KLFDSQL;
            KLFDSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Clear();
            KLFDSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("GBID", DbType.String, userName); //User.Identity.Name); //TODO

            KLFDDropDownList.DataBind();
</code>

Comment: as you have commented Databind line, just for confirmation, it would be not throwing error now

Comment: and if you are using this line, then where you providing the data source for dropdown

Comment: true, sorry, debugging at the same time... but then I don't get the new data either...

Comment: sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: you are not providing data source for dropdown, i suggest to create a function for binding drop down, and call it in inside if(!page.ispostback) so that it would bind dropdown again

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="KLFDDropDownList" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="KLFDSqlDataSource" DataTextField="FDEXTOM" 
        OnDataBound="KLFDDropDownList_DataBound"
        OnDataBinding="KLFDDropDownList_DataBinding"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="KLFDDropDownList_TextChanged"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        DataValueField="FDCD">

Comment: thanks man, I found it... I used SelectedIndex in the databound function... Issue solved, thanks a lot!